# How to encapsulate Method with generic type constraints

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

i've got a question and I do not have a clue of how to do it. Actually I'm not sure if the title is right.

I want to encapsulate a method which has generic params. The idea is to add some logging calls etc. around the method call.

Therefore this function

```
public void Load<T>(T spObject, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] retrievals)
{
    try
    {
      ... .Load(spObject, retrievals);}...
    }
}
```

should encapsulate a function which looks like this.

```
public void Load<T>(T spObject, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] retrievals) 
where T : ClientObject
```

The `Where T : ClientObject` has to be removed because it would need to reference an additional `dll` in another project.

When I try to remove the where i get an error saying

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.Load(T, params ...

Hope some have an Idea how I could handle this.

Thanks :-)
Greetz

Comment: because Load method contains the constraint, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536388.aspx, if you remove it from your load method, it can be that the user of your method pass to ClientRuntimeContext.Load method an object which is not ClientObject

Comment: Is there an other way to enure that the object is from ClientObject is ? on method call side ?

Comment: what about reflaction?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an encapsulation problem but an indirect reference one.

If you don' want to link to this "other" dll but you still want to use the `load` method, then you'll need to directly reference `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject` since that's the class that the `where` clause of the `load` method needs to use.

This is what you nee to add to your source files:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

Then you will need to add

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
```

to your project references. The dlls should be in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SharePoint Client` or in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI` depending on your sharepoint version.

This should be enough to compile and link your program.

Comment: I know what you mean .. Thank. But where should I reference the dll ? Can I directly refernce at the method or where ?